# Sonata User Bundle + Symfony 3.x

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony, sonata-user-bundle

I use Symfony 3.0.6, Sontata Admin Bundle 3.0.0 and the Doctrine ORM Admin Bundle on dev-master. The user bundle doesnt work even with dev-master. Is there a solution for Symfony 3.x yet?

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of 
packages.

Problem 1
  - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.0.6
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.6
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.5
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.4
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.3
  - Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master ->
satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[dev-master].
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.2
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.0.1
  - sonata-project/user-bundle dev-master requires symfony/form ^2.3 -> 
satisfiable by symfony/form[.....
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SonataUserBundle just released a 3.0.0 version 3 days ago, but does not seem to be compatible with SF3 yet, given the composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "sonata-project/user-bundle",
    "require": {
        "php": "^5.3 || ^7.0",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "^2.3",
        "symfony/form": "^2.3",
        "symfony/security": "^2.3",
        "symfony/console": "^2.3",
    },
    [...]
}
```

I am afraid we will have to wait a little bit longer.

Some issues were posted about it on the official repository:
https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/724

The author's answer:

> SF 3.0 is not supported because FOSUser 1.x does not support it.
>
> FOSUser 2.x is not stable and is not supported by our bundle right now.

---

For the complete story, there were plans to release a SF3 compatible version of the FOSUserBundle on december 2015, but no news about that one has came since...

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/pull/1990

Let's wait & see!

Comment: Well, it's a community project, anyone can contribute :)

Comment: Do you see todo list for S3 in github?

Comment: Nope, I do not use FOS/UserBundle neither Sonata for now, do I am not aware of any roadmap about it.

Comment: Same here. We are using SF3 and the FOS user bundle 2.0@dev to get it run with SF3. But the Sonata User Bundle only supports FOS 1.x for now which itself is not compatible with SF3. It's a deadlock state. 
Hope we can use FOS user bundle with SF3 in the near future. :)