# How do i install fos-user-bundle "@2.0" alongside with Sonata-user-bundle?

Tags: fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle, symfony-3.2

I'm new to **symfony framework**
I installed [FOSUserBundle "@2.0"](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) and [SonataAdminBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html)
they are both working fine
now i wanted to install **SonataUserBundle** to manage my users
but in the downloading process [via composer] he said that SonataUserBundle is only compatible with FOSUserBundle "*1.3"

- what SonataUserBundle accomplish ?
- How can i install it with fos-user-bundle ***"@2.0"***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonata User Bundle + Symfony 3.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315536/sonata-user-bundle-symfony-3-x)

Comment: yes
SonataUserBundle is compatible with FOSUserBundle 1.3
and Symfony 3 is compatible with FOSUserBundle 2.0
so there's no way to do it so ...
the only way is to wait for SonataUserBundle upgrade to be compatible with FOSUserBundle 2.0

Answer (score 2):

For now **SonataUserBundle** doesn't support **FOSUserBundle** "2.0".
But there is alternative brunch - **add_support_for_fos_user2**. 
You can plug it by this line:

```
composer require sonata-project/user-bundle dev-add_support_for_fos_user2
```

> NOTE:

This bundle requires PHP >= 7.0 version.

Point it out in composer.json file (for example v. 7.1.0):

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "7.1.0"
    }
},
```