# Symfony 3 and Sonata User Bundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

I am using Symfony 3.2 and Sonata Admin 3 , when I tried to install the Sonata User Bundle, it gave me this error :

```
C:\wamp64\www\backend>php ../composer.phar require sonata-project/user-bundle
Using version ^3.2 for sonata-project/user-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (locked at v2.0.0, required as ^1.3) is satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v2.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.3
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.2.8
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^1.3 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v1.3.0, v1.3.1, v1.3.2, v1.3.3, v1.3.4, v1.3.5, v1.3.6, v1.3.7].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.8
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v1.3.0 requires symfony/security-bundle 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/security-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
    - don't install symfony/security-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.8
    - ...


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

This is the composer.json file :

```
"php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.2",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^1.3",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "~1.4",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle": "^2.13",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^3.17",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^3.1",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3.10",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.2.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
```

Is there a way to use this combination: symfony 3 , sonata user 3 and fos user 2.0.0.  Or I should symfony 2 sonata user 3 and fos user 1.3 ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonata User Bundle + Symfony 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315536/sonata-user-bundle-symfony-3-x)

Answer (score 2):

stable version of SonataUserBundle use Symfony 2.3, to use with symfony3 must use the development version 4 (dev-master)

```
"sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master"
```

Answer (score 0):

Heyho,
is a stables version planed?